# How can I adjust code block and output size on specific slides of a Quarto revealjs presentation in R?

Tags: r, quarto, reveal.js

I would like to increase the size of code block (avoiding horizontal slider) but for only a particular slides (not for all of them) in Quarto presentation.
I want to increase width in order not to use horizontal slider, because I have got enough space to the right side of layout (1).
I want to scale up output as well, because it looks a bit tiny on screen and I have got a place for it to the right side and downwards as well (2).

[image]

````
---
title: "Flex"
format: 
  revealjs:
    slideNumber: true
    self-contained: true
editor: visual
execute: 
  echo: true
  include: true
  output: true
---

## Slide_1

```{r}
#| label: my_chunk_1 - defining M.
#| output-location: column-fragment

library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(tidyverse)

M <- as.table(rbind(c(762, 327, 468), c(484, 239, 477)))
dimnames(M) <- list(gender = c("F", "M"), party = c("Democrat", "Independent", "Republican"))


M
```

## Slide_2

```{r}
#| label: my_chunk_2 - showing M.
#| output-location: column-fragment
M <- as.data.frame(M) 

M
```

## Slide_3

```{r}
#| label: my_chunk_3 - uncounting M.
#| output-location: column-fragment

M <- M |> uncount(Freq)

M
```

## Slide_4

```{r}
#| label: my_chunk_4 - defining f.
#| output-location: column-fragment

f <- ftable(M,
            row.vars = "gender",
            col.vars = c("party"))


ftable_to_flextable <- function( x ){

  row.vars = attr( x, "row.vars" )
  col.vars = attr( x, "col.vars" )
  rows <- rev( expand.grid( rev(row.vars), stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) )
  cols <- rev(expand.grid( rev(col.vars), stringsAsFactors = FALSE ))

  xmat <- as.matrix(x)
  cols$col_keys = dimnames(xmat)[[2]]
  xdata <- cbind(
    data.frame(rows, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    data.frame(xmat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  )
  names(xdata) <- c(names(row.vars), cols$col_keys)

  ft <- flextable(xdata)
  ft <- set_header_df(ft, cols)
  ft <- theme_booktabs(ft)
  ft <- merge_v(ft, j = names(row.vars))
  ft
}

f
```

## Slide_5

```{r}
#| label: my_chunk_5_ftable_to_flextable
#| tbl-cap: Description of my flextable
#| output-location: column-fragment

final <- ftable(M) %>% ftable_to_flextable()

final

```
````

[image]

Thank you for your help regarding this matter.

Comment: for the fist question simply put `ftable_to_flex` into a newline.

Comment: You are using `output-location: column-fragment` in all of your slides. And your first posted pic does not match with any code shown here.  I think you should post a minimal reproducible example (may be with a single slide) that showcases the specific problem.

Comment: My first picture is a just an example, I provided reprex and with Slide_5 it shows exactly the same situation and this is included in a reprex.

Comment: Oh ok. Anyway, as I have said the reason you are having horizontal scrollbars is that `output-location: column-fragment`, so that output can be placed on the right side of the code chunk.

Comment: I am happy to have output on the right hand side of the code chunk, but there is alot of space to fill (1) to the right and (2) to the right and downwards as well. How do I do it to scale up the output, in order to be more readable ? On the other hand if I increase size of code chunk to the right (1) I will not need horizontal slider as well. How do I do it, please ?